# draw the graph in the plane with no crossing and such that every edge is a straight line

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I tried many times but I still cannot find such graph.
Is there any algorithm for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is in fact planar, then yes: see [Fary's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem).  That is however assuming that it is in fact planar.  You might check a number of ways to prove that it is not planar first however.  For example, how many edges are in the graph?  How many vertices?  What inequality should you see comparing these?  For graphs like this where the edge density appears large, this is one of the first steps I take is.  If that doesn't immediately give a conclusion but I still feel like it might not be possible, I turn to Kuratowski's criterion next.

Comment: Playing with the graph a little while on [this applet](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3550), I can confirm that it is in fact planar so that can save you some time from searching for reasons why it shouldn't be.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh my god this is sooooo amazing! Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, the inequality I was alluding to was that for planar graphs we must have $e\leq 3v-6$, but unfortunately (*or fortunately*) here the inequality was in fact an equality with $e=18$ and $v=8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [this applet](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3550) for playing around with graphs.  The general algorithm can be found in texts such as Diestel's Graph Theory, but the idea being that you start building a planar graph out of a subset of the vertices using cycles.  Then when adding the next cycle, if it fits already, great.  If it doesn't, invert what you have already done.  See [Fary's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem).

[image]

Try playing around with the app a bit more before looking at the answer I found.

> [image]